# Fastest way to delete part of word from end of word?

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

Let's say I have the following text and my cursor is on the "d"

```
someCamelCaseWord
                ^
```

I want to delete "Word" so that the text reads "someCamelCase"

What's the fewest number of keystrokes required to achieve this?

Comment: is it specifically to delete `Word` or you have a generic names like `sampleVarNameAbc` where you would like to delete last sequence of letter beginning with uppercase (Abc in this case)?

Comment: @spasic The more general case

Comment: Highlight with mouse, `x`.

Comment: @Antony, _Highlight with mouse_ is the first thing you would want to avoid using vim.

Comment: FYI: I am now using a plugin that adds a new text object and motion for camel-case sub-words. I configured the plugin such that the text object is described by the key-sequence `gw`. If I want to delete a camel-case sub-word, I just type `digw` (instead of `diw`, which would delete the entire word). The plugin: https://github.com/chaoren/vim-wordmotion An alternative plugin: https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this specific instance, the best I could come up with is 4, including holding the shift key. There are several possibilities.

xxxx - delete the character under the cursor.
3Xx - delete 3 characters to the left, delete the character under the cursor.
3hdw - Move 3 characters to the left, delete to the end of the word.
3hD - Move 3 characters to the left, delete to the end of the line.

Other tries, with 5 keystrokes[1], that doesn't use repeated commands or movement counts:

dFWx - delete, moving left to the 'W', then delete the remaining character, since the 'd' does not delete the character under the cursor, when moving left.
FWdw - move left to the 'W', then delete to the end of the word.

1 - I only count them as 5 due to holding the shift key down for consecutive keystrokes.

Comment: FWD is only three letters.

Comment: But 4 keystrokes, counting the shift or caps lock key.

Comment: `FWdw` should be `FWde` and `3hdw` should be `3hde`. `3hD` assumes a bit to much.

Comment: Also `vFWd` or `v3hx` and `vFWc` if you want go to insert mode.

Comment: Thanks for counting Shift as a key stroke. I think I'll stick to FWdw, where W can vary based on the word. It is 5 key strokes instead of 4 like the others, but I think it is has the least cognitive friction since I don't have to count how many characters the word consists of, which would be difficult if the word I'm trying to delete is long.

Answer (score 1):

One.

Press x and hold. Wait until it deletes 4 characters, then release it.

Comment: Having mixed feelings about this solution. I'd say OK in this case. But what if  `ThatIsAVeryLongCamelCaseName` which can happen ? Plus  it's kind of like using backspace in other editors.

Comment: I'm not feeling that the 'press and hold' is a great solution, it minimizes the number of different keystroke, but anything that require "holding" a key seems nonoptimal.

Comment: Of course press and hold isn't a great way to delete characters. It's a dreadful way to do it. But the request wasn't for a sensible way to do it, it was for the shortest way to do it, purely in terms of keystrokes. And one keystroke is going to be hard to beat.

Comment: It's not the shortest if your SSH link is flaky and you have to clean up after it.

Comment: If you delete one or two characters too many or too few, you can press u or x two or three times, and still do as well as or better than any of the 'sane' options. (defining better only in terms of number of keystrokes of course).
Oddly, it's easier to get it right first time if you are working on ThatIsAVeryLongCamelCaseName because once it starts deleting you have longer to work out when to lift your finger. 
Again, this isn't a recommendable way to delete 4 characters, just one that uses the minimum possible key strokes.

Comment: This whole question should probably be moved to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

As you said, your cursor is positioned at `d`. Thus with `?W` you can jump the cursor position to `W` and with  `cw` or `dw` you can remove `Word`.

In total this is 4 keys pressed, but this saves time on counting characters needed for something like multiple `x` keypresses or `4h`. Especially will be useful for targeting the capital letter of camelcase words. For instance , with `public static void PaymentsSubmittedToday` string and cursor at `y` , we can just do `?S` then `dw`, and the string becomes `public static void Payments` with cursor at `s`

Answer (score -1):

```
dFW
```

Search backwards for the fist W, and delete everything up-to and including it. `d` means delete and `FW` is a motion command that means move the cursor backwards to the first encountered `W` character.

Comment: This doesn't work, as it will not delete the character under the cursor, in this case the final 'd'